# How to paint cells in row (Telerik)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I've next code that handle fowFormatting my cells:

```
private void gridViewRaces_RowFormatting(object sender, RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var cellColumn in e.RowElement.Data.Cells)
        {
            var cellInfo = cellColumn as GridViewCellInfo;
            if (cellInfo != null)
            {
                cellInfo.Style.DrawFill = true;
                if (cellInfo.ColumnInfo.Name == "columnContactProducerName")
                {
                    cellInfo.Style.DrawFill = true;
                    cellInfo.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else if (cellInfo.ColumnInfo.Name == "columnTransport")
                {
                    cellInfo.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellInfo.Style.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml((e.RowElement.Data.DataBoundItem as RaceForListDto).Color);
                }
            }

        }
        //e.RowElement.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml((e.RowElement.Data.DataBoundItem as RaceForListDto).Color);
    }
```

but my cells aren't painting. How to paint some cells in rows on dataBinding?

Comment: Are you using WebForms?  MVC?  WPF?

Comment: I'm using webforms

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the proper event to do this is ItemDataBound event. See here:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/appearance-and-styling/conditional-formatting

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
//Is it a GridDataItem
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
    //Get the instance of the right type
    GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

    //Check the formatting condition
    if (int.Parse(dataBoundItem["Size"].Text) > 100)
    {
        dataBoundItem["Received"].ForeColor = Color.Red;
        dataBoundItem["Received"].Font.Bold = true;
        //Customize more...
    }
}
}
```

Or event better is to use a custom CSS class so that you can later make changes without having to rebuild the project:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e){
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
    GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    if (dataItem["Country"].Text == "Mexico")
        dataItem.CssClass = "MyMexicoRowClass";
}
}
```